# How do I create a table in excel based on 2 values in another table

Tags: excel

Hi I want to generate values in a table based on 2 values in another table. It's difficult to explain this problem in words so I will attempt to explain it with an example.
Example: data in table 1 needs to be used to populate values in table 2

Table 1:

```
Building type             Number
Hospital                     4           
Fire station                 2
Hotel.                       0
```

Table 2

```
Hospital 1
Hospital 2
Hospital  3
Hospital  4
Fire station 1
Fire station 2
```

Note if the number is 0 in column 2 of table 1, no corresponding value should be created in table 2.

Comment: Hey Thanks @jnevill for this. This worked really well for me. What would i need to change in the code if number is not in column 2 bit in column 10 instead. Also, what do I need to change if i add another column say city and need to move that to table 2 corresponding to the building type.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quickly with some VBA:

```
Sub makenewtable()
    Dim rngTable1 As Range
    Dim rngTable2 As Range
    Dim rngReadRow As Range
    Dim intWriteRow As Integer
    Dim intLoop As Integer

    'set this to your first table
    Set rngTable1 = Sheet1.Range("A2:B4")

    'set this to the first row to write to:
    Set rngTable2 = Sheet2.Range("A2")
    rngWriteRow = 0

    'Loop through the first table row by row
    For Each rngReadRow In rngTable1.Rows
        'Loop the number of times the first table says we should
        For intLoop = 1 To rngReadRow.Cells(1, 2).Value
            'write the value out to the second table
            rngTable2.Offset(rngWriteRow, 0) = rngReadRow.Cells(1, 1).Value
            rngTable2.Offset(rngWriteRow, 1) = intLoop

            'increment the row to which we are writing
            rngWriteRow = rngWriteRow + 1
        Next
    Next rngReadRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Thanks @jnevill for this. This worked really well for me. What would i need to change in the code if number is not in column 2 bit in column 10 instead. Also, what do I need to change if i add another column say city and need to move that to table 2 corresponding to the building type.

Comment: Change your `rngTable1` to go out to column J: `Set rngTable1 = Sheet1.Range("A2:J4")` and then change which `Cells()` you use to determine your loop: `For intLoop = 1 To rngReadRow.Cells(1, 10).Value`